disable log out screen not success
I have below settings already, but ubuntu (22.04) still logout me after sometime. Since I am running ubuntun on vitualbox, then logout will cause ubuntu freeze then I have to reset it.


Do you mean that a screen saver comes on after a period of inactivity? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Edit your question and add all these information.
